# Rails where date is monday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 6, how can I write a `where` query who find all records with a date attributes that is a monday ?

Something like : `Appointment.where(date: monday?)`

or `Appointment.where('date.wday': 1)`

Answer (score 2):

This is working with Postgres :

`Appointment.where("extract(dow from date) = ?", Date.current.monday.wday)`

Comment: This is how I would do too, but I would use `Date.current.monday.wday` instead of the static `1` just for the sake clarification so whoever reads this code, knows that this is listing all `monday` appointments

Comment: You're right, I'm changing the answer